# Set Teams Picture using graph API

Tags: image, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to set the team's picture using graph API. I am using the SDK version.

```
                byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\TeamPhoto.png");
                string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);

                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64ImageRepresentation);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    var d = await graphClient.Groups[teamId].Photo.Content
                    .Request()
                    .PutAsync(ms);
                }
```

But I am getting an error

> Unable to to set photo of target in Outlook Exchange Photo API:
> PhotoApiCallServiceException

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing here?

StackTrace:

```
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendStreamRequestAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [this c# code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) replacing `Me` with Groups["teamid"]. And get the binary of Image using the below code.

Comment: public static byte[] ImageToBinary(string imagePath)
{
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
    fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
    fileStream.Close();
    return buffer;
}

Comment: See if it works.

Comment: Getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share the whole stack trace of the Exception

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma added the stacktrace